# Unable to convert json response to list. Casting error

Tags: api, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to convert my json response to list but getting the below error.
Json is fetched inside map ,but need to convert map to list and display in listview.

```
"_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'"
```

Json Response

```
{"78":{"id":118,"first_name":"test","last_name":null,"email":"jignesh.test@gmail.com","phone":"","city":"null","state":"null","countrie_id":1,"location":"null","lat":"37.421998333333335","lng":"-122.08400000000002","image":"","role_id":3,"client_id":3,"coordinator_id":1,"sst_id":2,"created_at":"2018-10-08 10:59:18","updated_at":"2018-10-08 10:59:18","deleted_at":null,"status":0},
"79":{"id":119,"first_name":"Rahul test","last_name":null,"email":"rahul.test@gmail.com","phone":"","city":"null","state":"null","countrie_id":1,"location":"null","lat":"19.2284","lng":"72.85813","image":"","role_id":3,"client_id":3,"coordinator_id":1,"sst_id":2,"created_at":"2018-10-08 11:19:14","updated_at":"2018-10-08 11:19:14","deleted_at":null,"status":0},
"80":{"id":120,"first_name":"Customer Name","last_name":null,"email":"jjkkk@gmail.com","phone":"","city":"Mumbai","state":"Maharastra","countrie_id":1,"location":"virar","lat":"123","lng":"456","image":"images\/customer_image\/0hUSFUSqYAQTt57bVnnHjuQUOACECWzBOfJLWWa6.png","role_id":3,"client_id":1,"coordinator_id":1,"sst_id":2,"created_at":"2018-10-09 12:24:08","updated_at":"2018-10-09 14:03:07","deleted_at":null,"status":0},"status":"success","message":"List Fetched Successfully."}
```

Below is my Future method for calling post api method.

```
 Future<PosModelData> posList(){
  print('pos list api called');
  return networkUtil.post("http://192.168.0.46/api/v1/poslist",body:{
      "sstId":"2"
  }).then((response){
    if(response["status"]=="success"){
      print("List fetched");
      posLists=((response) as List).map((data)=>new PosModelData.fromJson(data)).toList();
      // print(response.toString());
      // print(posLists);
    }
  });
}
```

PosModel.dart

```
    class PosModelData {
  final String first_name;
  final String last_name;
  final String email;

  PosModelData({this.first_name, this.last_name, this.email});

  factory PosModelData.fromJson(Map json) {
    return new PosModelData(
      first_name: json['first_name'],
      last_name: json['last_name'],
      email: json['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

NetworkUtil.dart

```
Future<dynamic> post(String url, {Map header, body, encoding}) {
return http
    .post(url, body: body, headers: header, encoding: encoding)
    .then((http.Response response) {
  final String resBody = response.body;

  return jsonDecoder.convert(resBody);
});
}
```

Comment: what kind of object `networkUtil.post` is returning ? you are using `response["status"]` as a Map, but you are trying to cast as a List `posLists=((response) as List)`

Comment: hi i have added network util class,

Comment: print your response, `print(response)`, it seems to me that it is a `Map<String, dynamic>` so you cannot cast it to List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your json string/response is not properly created.

In the same Map you have the status and then each element of your List so it's not possible to extract the List. You can reformat the server response and then get as shown in this code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

String responseStr = '''
{
"status":"success",
"message":"List Fetched Successfully.",
"posts":
  [
    {"id":118,"first_name":"test","last_name":null,"email":"jignesh.test@gmail.com","phone":"","city":"null","state":"null","countrie_id":1,"location":"null","lat":"37.421998333333335","lng":"-122.08400000000002","image":"","role_id":3,"client_id":3,"coordinator_id":1,"sst_id":2,"created_at":"2018-10-08 10:59:18","updated_at":"2018-10-08 10:59:18","deleted_at":null,"status":0},
    {"id":119,"first_name":"Rahul test","last_name":null,"email":"rahul.test@gmail.com","phone":"","city":"null","state":"null","countrie_id":1,"location":"null","lat":"19.2284","lng":"72.85813","image":"","role_id":3,"client_id":3,"coordinator_id":1,"sst_id":2,"created_at":"2018-10-08 11:19:14","updated_at":"2018-10-08 11:19:14","deleted_at":null,"status":0},
    {"id":120,"first_name":"Customer Name","last_name":null,"email":"jjkkk@gmail.com","phone":"","city":"Mumbai","state":"Maharastra","countrie_id":1,"location":"virar","lat":"123","lng":"456","image":"images\/customer_image\/0hUSFUSqYAQTt57bVnnHjuQUOACECWzBOfJLWWa6.png","role_id":3,"client_id":1,"coordinator_id":1,"sst_id":2,"created_at":"2018-10-09 12:24:08","updated_at":"2018-10-09 14:03:07","deleted_at":null,"status":0}
  ]
}
''';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<PosModelData> postList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPosts();
  }

  Future<Null> getPosts() async {
    // Your http logic
    Map<String, dynamic> response = json.decode(responseStr);
    if (response["status"] == "success") {
      postList = ((response["posts"]) as List)
          .map((data) => new PosModelData.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: postList != null ?
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("${postList[0].first_name} ${postList[0].email}"),
            new Text("${postList[1].first_name} ${postList[1].email}"),
            new Text("${postList[2].first_name} ${postList[2].email}"),
          ],
        ) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PosModelData {
  final String first_name;
  final String last_name;
  final String email;

  PosModelData({this.first_name, this.last_name, this.email});

  factory PosModelData.fromJson(Map json) {
    return new PosModelData(
      first_name: json['first_name'],
      last_name: json['last_name'],
      email: json['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx i asked my backend guys to change the response and voila it worked .

Answer (score 0):

You assume that your JSON response is list of objects, while in fact it is a single object with keys that maps to `PosModelData`.

You should either change your server response to something like:

```
[
   {
      "id":118,
      "first_name":"test",
      "last_name":null,
      ...
   },
   {
      "id":119,
      "first_name":"Rahul test",
      "last_name":null,
      ...
   }
]
```

or change the way you parse JSON response.

Comment: Thanx it seems to work when i change the response to the one you posted. Thanx alot